# Place two font icons one above the other with CSS

Tags: css, css-position

I want to place two font icons one above the other. So I can use it as:

```
<span class="icon1-on-icon2" />
```

Is it possible to define CSS class(es) to achieve this? It's **not** permitted to use another elements inside a span i.e. something like that:

```
<span class="stack">
   <span class="icon1"/>
   <span class="icon2" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, why not use :after and :before pseudo-selectors?

**CSS**

```
.font-icon {
  height: 40px;
  width: 20px;
}

.font-icon:after, .font-icon:before {
  color: white;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  font-family: 'your-font-icon';
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
}

.font-icon:before {
  background: red;
  content: 'h';
}

.font-icon:after {
  background: blue;
  content: 'g';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class='font-icon'></span>
```

Codepen sketch here: http://cdpn.io/lehzr

**UPDATE**

To place them on top of each other, simply change the position to absolute, put a relative on the container element, and set top and left to 0 for both the after and before.

Example: http://cdpn.io/lehzr

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to place one icon on the other icon.  So they would have the same position.

Comment: If I change your answer to position:absolte that is what I was looking for !

Comment: Yes, I just put an answer with updated sketch to show that. Nice! :)